# Sending Data to SQL after x amount of ¦ lines

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

im new to C# and i was wondering if it was possible to send data to sql after 7 or so pipe characters (`'|'`) in a line of text,

I currently have the following

```
// Read each line of the file into a string array. Each element of the array is one line of the file.
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\WatchFolder\WriteLines2.txt");

// Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.

int count = 0;

char[] splitchar = { '|' };
System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteLines2.txt = ");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] strArr = null;

    strArr = line.Split(splitchar);
    int iLen = strArr.Length - 1;
    for (count = 0; count <= iLen; count++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(strArr[count]);
    }

}

// Keep the console window open in debug mode.
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
System.Console.ReadKey();
```

The above currently displays the contents of a text file and then outputs all the data in console on each line.

thanks

Comment: u mean u want to save each 7 lines in the db ?

Comment: define "send data to sql" - that's pretty vague; and what is the significance of the 7 here? what is the context? what is the distinction between rows (`lines`) and columns (`strArr`) here? this is all very vague. But to answer the question "if it was possible": yes, absolutely; **how** depends on the context

Comment: What do you mean by "7 pipe lines in a line of text"? By definition, a line of text cannot contain multiple other lines.

Comment: @Binarus I'm guessing "pipe lines" here simply means: `|`

Comment: @Marc Gravell I see. Thank you. He means the pipe character.

Comment: My basic understanding is that the OP has a text file , he want to store each 7 lines in the db.... I am waiting for his reply

Comment: Example input & what is expected in the database would be useful.

Comment: Yes i would like to save each lines in the db the structure is:

[DIWOR][earnercode][earnerNAME][DEPT_CODE][Nt_user_name][ActDate][Blank][Status][Office][Dept][Dated][ID] here is the fields and in between each field is a pipe line '|'

Comment: to my understanding i will need to count the '|' in the file for X times and then push data to sql every time X is fulfilled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question (even with the clarifications in the comments) is not fully clear, but this is my current guess:

You have a text file with lines of pipe `|` separated data. For each line of data, you want to capture the first seven values, and discard the rest. The captured data should be sent to the database for further processing.

If I am correct, then you want to modify your existing code like so:

```
...
string[] strArr;
string[] newArray = new string[7];  

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    strArr = line.Split(splitchar);
    Array.Copy(strArr, newArray, 7);

    // Call DB function, passing newArray
    saveToDB(newArray);
}
...
```

Comment: just modified this slightly and got it to work, thanks alot